# format table to have mean (sd) instead of separate columns R

Tags: r, dataframe

I Have a data frame of several water quality measures. For each measure I have a calculated mean and SD. I have a value for 6 sites and 4 seasons. Currently my dataframe has the means in a column for examples 'Temp_1' and then a column for the standard deviation as 'Temp_2'. I want to export the file with one column for each water quality measure with the format mean (SD).

#### current output

This is an example for the first water measure, but I'd like to code it so it is also done to remaining factors as well.

[image]

#### desired output

[image]

#### Head of dataframe

```
structure(list(season = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Winter", 
"Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"), class = "factor"), Site = structure(1:6, levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), Temp_1 = c(7.2, 
7.05, 6.3, 6.25, 6.2, 5.4), Temp_2 = c(1.55563491861041, 1.90918830920368, 
1.69705627484771, 2.33345237791561, 2.40416305603426, 2.40416305603426
), pH_1 = c(7.435, 7.38, 7.52, 7.525, 7.38, 7.565), pH_2 = c(0.289913780286484, 
0.282842712474619, 0.0989949493661164, 0.120208152801713, 0.0565685424949239, 
0.261629509039023), DO_1 = c(9, 9.1, 8.25, 8.85, 9.25, 9), DO_2 = c(0, 
0.424264068711928, 0.0707106781186558, 0.494974746830583, 0.636396103067892, 
0.42426406871193), EC_1 = c(337.5, 333, 321.5, 322, 309, 300.5
), EC_2 = c(55.8614357137373, 41.0121933088198, 51.618795026618, 
32.5269119345812, 25.4558441227157, 30.4055915910215), SS_1 = c(5.945, 
3.65, 5.025, 2.535, 10.22, 4.595), SS_2 = c(0.728319984622144, 
1.06066017177982, 2.93449314192417, 0.473761543394987, 8.23072293301141, 
0.67175144212722), TP_1 = c(73.5, 75, 61.5, 66.5, 83, 87), TP_2 = c(3.53553390593274, 
12.7279220613579, 9.19238815542512, 6.36396103067893, 26.8700576850888, 
24.0416305603426), SRP_1 = c(19, 19, 10, 14, 13.5, 23.5), SRP_2 = c(2.82842712474619, 
1.4142135623731, 2.82842712474619, 0, 0.707106781186548, 3.53553390593274
), PP_1 = c(54.5, 56, 51.5, 52.5, 69.5, 63.5), PP_2 = c(6.36396103067893, 
11.3137084989848, 6.36396103067893, 6.36396103067893, 26.1629509039023, 
20.5060966544099), DA_1 = c(0.083, 0.0775, 0.0775, 0.044, 0.059, 
0.051), DA_2 = c(0.00282842712474619, 0.0120208152801713, 0.00919238815542513, 
0.0014142135623731, 0.0127279220613579, 0.00848528137423857), 
    DNI_1 = c(0.048739437, 0.041015562, 0.0617723365, 0.0337441755, 
    0.041480944, 0.0143461675), DNI_2 = c(0.0345079125942686, 
    0.0223312453226695, 0.0187360224120165, 0.0162032493604065, 
    0.0258169069873252, 0.0202885446465761), DNA_1 = c(20.43507986, 
    20.438919615, 14.98692746, 19.953408625, 17.03060377, 8.5767502525
    ), DNA_2 = c(1.80288106961836, 1.2687128010491, 2.28839365291436, 
    1.03116172040732, 0.396528484042397, 1.72350828181138), DF_1 = c(0.0992379715, 
    0.0947268395, 0.094323125, 0.098064875, 0.0980304675, 0.085783911
    ), DF_2 = c(0.00372072305060515, 0.00724914346231915, 0.0142932471712976, 
    0.0116895470668939, 0.00255671780854136, 0.00830519117656529
    ), DC_1 = c(12.18685357, 12.73924378, 13.09550326, 13.417557825, 
    15.140975265, 21.429763715), DC_2 = c(0.57615880774946, 0.0430071960969884, 
    0.702539578486863, 0.134642528587041, 0.66786605299916, 0.17012889453292
    ), DS_1 = c(15.834380095, 15.69623116, 14.37636388, 15.444235935, 
    14.647596185, 11.9877372), DS_2 = c(1.67153135346354, 1.69978765863781, 
    2.47560570280853, 1.03831263471691, 1.24488755930594, 0.975483163720397
    ), DOC_1 = c(19.74, 20.08, 21.24, 20.34, 21.88, 24.92), DOC_2 = c(2.7435743110038, 
    1.69705627484772, 2.60215295476649, 1.04651803615609, 0.226274169979695, 
    0.452548339959388)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mutate across with some tricks to organize paired data we can do it this way. Further adaptation is possible (for example just to keep the mean_sd columns (just use `transmute` instead of `mutate`):

**Update:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(-c(season, Site), ~round(.,2))) %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with('_1'), ~ paste0(.,
                                         "(",
                  get(str_replace(cur_column(), "_1$", "_2")),
                  ")"
                  ), .names = "mean_sd_{.col}")) %>%  
  rename_at(vars(starts_with('mean_sd')), ~ str_remove(., "\\_1"))
```

```
 season Site Temp_1 Temp_2 pH_1 pH_2 DO_1 DO_2  EC_1  EC_2  SS_1 SS_2 TP_1  TP_2 SRP_1 SRP_2 PP_1  PP_2 DA_1 DA_2 DNI_1 DNI_2 DNA_1 DNA_2 DF_1
1 Winter    1   7.20   1.56 7.43 0.29 9.00 0.00 337.5 55.86  5.94 0.73 73.5  3.54  19.0  2.83 54.5  6.36 0.08 0.00  0.05  0.03 20.44  1.80 0.10
2 Winter    2   7.05   1.91 7.38 0.28 9.10 0.42 333.0 41.01  3.65 1.06 75.0 12.73  19.0  1.41 56.0 11.31 0.08 0.01  0.04  0.02 20.44  1.27 0.09
3 Winter    3   6.30   1.70 7.52 0.10 8.25 0.07 321.5 51.62  5.03 2.93 61.5  9.19  10.0  2.83 51.5  6.36 0.08 0.01  0.06  0.02 14.99  2.29 0.09
4 Winter    4   6.25   2.33 7.53 0.12 8.85 0.49 322.0 32.53  2.54 0.47 66.5  6.36  14.0  0.00 52.5  6.36 0.04 0.00  0.03  0.02 19.95  1.03 0.10
5 Winter    5   6.20   2.40 7.38 0.06 9.25 0.64 309.0 25.46 10.22 8.23 83.0 26.87  13.5  0.71 69.5 26.16 0.06 0.01  0.04  0.03 17.03  0.40 0.10
6 Winter    6   5.40   2.40 7.57 0.26 9.00 0.42 300.5 30.41  4.60 0.67 87.0 24.04  23.5  3.54 63.5 20.51 0.05 0.01  0.01  0.02  8.58  1.72 0.09
  DF_2  DC_1 DC_2  DS_1 DS_2 DOC_1 DOC_2 mean_sd_Temp mean_sd_pH mean_sd_DO   mean_sd_EC  mean_sd_SS mean_sd_TP mean_sd_SRP  mean_sd_PP mean_sd_DA
1 0.00 12.19 0.58 15.83 1.67 19.74  2.74    7.2(1.56) 7.43(0.29)       9(0) 337.5(55.86)  5.94(0.73) 73.5(3.54)    19(2.83)  54.5(6.36)    0.08(0)
2 0.01 12.74 0.04 15.70 1.70 20.08  1.70   7.05(1.91) 7.38(0.28)  9.1(0.42)   333(41.01)  3.65(1.06)  75(12.73)    19(1.41)   56(11.31) 0.08(0.01)
3 0.01 13.10 0.70 14.38 2.48 21.24  2.60     6.3(1.7)  7.52(0.1) 8.25(0.07) 321.5(51.62)  5.03(2.93) 61.5(9.19)    10(2.83)  51.5(6.36) 0.08(0.01)
4 0.01 13.42 0.13 15.44 1.04 20.34  1.05   6.25(2.33) 7.53(0.12) 8.85(0.49)   322(32.53)  2.54(0.47) 66.5(6.36)       14(0)  52.5(6.36)    0.04(0)
5 0.00 15.14 0.67 14.65 1.24 21.88  0.23     6.2(2.4) 7.38(0.06) 9.25(0.64)   309(25.46) 10.22(8.23)  83(26.87)  13.5(0.71) 69.5(26.16) 0.06(0.01)
6 0.01 21.43 0.17 11.99 0.98 24.92  0.45     5.4(2.4) 7.57(0.26)    9(0.42) 300.5(30.41)   4.6(0.67)  87(24.04)  23.5(3.54) 63.5(20.51) 0.05(0.01)
  mean_sd_DNI mean_sd_DNA mean_sd_DF  mean_sd_DC  mean_sd_DS mean_sd_DOC
1  0.05(0.03)  20.44(1.8)     0.1(0) 12.19(0.58) 15.83(1.67) 19.74(2.74)
2  0.04(0.02) 20.44(1.27) 0.09(0.01) 12.74(0.04)   15.7(1.7)  20.08(1.7)
3  0.06(0.02) 14.99(2.29) 0.09(0.01)   13.1(0.7) 14.38(2.48)  21.24(2.6)
4  0.03(0.02) 19.95(1.03)  0.1(0.01) 13.42(0.13) 15.44(1.04) 20.34(1.05)
5  0.04(0.03)  17.03(0.4)     0.1(0) 15.14(0.67) 14.65(1.24) 21.88(0.23)
6  0.01(0.02)  8.58(1.72) 0.09(0.01) 21.43(0.17) 11.99(0.98) 24.92(0.45)
```

**First answer:**
We could do this like so:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(mean_sd = paste0(Temp_1, " (", round(Temp_2,2), ")"), .before=5)
```

```
  season Site Temp_1   Temp_2     mean_sd  pH_1       pH_2 DO_1       DO_2  EC_1     EC_2   SS_1      SS_2 TP_1      TP_2 SRP_1     SRP_2 PP_1
1 Winter    1   7.20 1.555635  7.2 (1.56) 7.435 0.28991378 9.00 0.00000000 337.5 55.86144  5.945 0.7283200 73.5  3.535534  19.0 2.8284271 54.5
2 Winter    2   7.05 1.909188 7.05 (1.91) 7.380 0.28284271 9.10 0.42426407 333.0 41.01219  3.650 1.0606602 75.0 12.727922  19.0 1.4142136 56.0
3 Winter    3   6.30 1.697056   6.3 (1.7) 7.520 0.09899495 8.25 0.07071068 321.5 51.61880  5.025 2.9344931 61.5  9.192388  10.0 2.8284271 51.5
4 Winter    4   6.25 2.333452 6.25 (2.33) 7.525 0.12020815 8.85 0.49497475 322.0 32.52691  2.535 0.4737615 66.5  6.363961  14.0 0.0000000 52.5
5 Winter    5   6.20 2.404163   6.2 (2.4) 7.380 0.05656854 9.25 0.63639610 309.0 25.45584 10.220 8.2307229 83.0 26.870058  13.5 0.7071068 69.5
6 Winter    6   5.40 2.404163   5.4 (2.4) 7.565 0.26162951 9.00 0.42426407 300.5 30.40559  4.595 0.6717514 87.0 24.041631  23.5 3.5355339 63.5
       PP_2   DA_1        DA_2      DNI_1      DNI_2    DNA_1     DNA_2       DF_1        DF_2     DC_1      DC_2     DS_1      DS_2 DOC_1
1  6.363961 0.0830 0.002828427 0.04873944 0.03450791 20.43508 1.8028811 0.09923797 0.003720723 12.18685 0.5761588 15.83438 1.6715314 19.74
2 11.313708 0.0775 0.012020815 0.04101556 0.02233125 20.43892 1.2687128 0.09472684 0.007249143 12.73924 0.0430072 15.69623 1.6997877 20.08
3  6.363961 0.0775 0.009192388 0.06177234 0.01873602 14.98693 2.2883937 0.09432312 0.014293247 13.09550 0.7025396 14.37636 2.4756057 21.24
4  6.363961 0.0440 0.001414214 0.03374418 0.01620325 19.95341 1.0311617 0.09806487 0.011689547 13.41756 0.1346425 15.44424 1.0383126 20.34
5 26.162951 0.0590 0.012727922 0.04148094 0.02581691 17.03060 0.3965285 0.09803047 0.002556718 15.14098 0.6678661 14.64760 1.2448876 21.88
6 20.506097 0.0510 0.008485281 0.01434617 0.02028854  8.57675 1.7235083 0.08578391 0.008305191 21.42976 0.1701289 11.98774 0.9754832 24.92
      DOC_2
1 2.7435743
2 1.6970563
3 2.6021530
4 1.0465180
5 0.2262742
6 0.4525483
```

Comment: Yes, but for all of the factors

Comment: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `mean_sd_Temp_1`.
Caused by error in `str_replace()`:
! could not find function "str_replace"
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Hi @TarJAe - I got the above errors.

Comment: Ah sorry library(stringr) please add.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column like this

```
df$Temp <- paste0(df$Temp_1, ' (', df$Temp_2, ')')
```

And select only the desired output columns

```
df[, c('season', 'Site', 'Temp')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  pivot_longer(-c(season, Site)) %>%  
  mutate(name = name %>% str_remove_all("[^a-zA-Z]")) %>%  
  group_by(season, Site, name) %>%
  summarise(value = str_c(round(value, 2), collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, 
              values_from = value) 

# A tibble: 6 x 17
# Groups:   season, Site [6]
  season Site  DA         DC          DF         DNA         DNI        DO       DOC   DS    EC    pH    PP    SRP   SS    Temp  TP   
  <fct>  <fct> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Winter 1     0.08, 0    12.19, 0.58 0.1, 0     20.44, 1.8  0.05, 0.03 9, 0     19.7~ 15.8~ 337.~ 7.43~ 54.5~ 19, ~ 5.94~ 7.2,~ 73.5~
2 Winter 2     0.08, 0.01 12.74, 0.04 0.09, 0.01 20.44, 1.27 0.04, 0.02 9.1, 0.~ 20.0~ 15.7~ 333,~ 7.38~ 56, ~ 19, ~ 3.65~ 7.05~ 75, ~
3 Winter 3     0.08, 0.01 13.1, 0.7   0.09, 0.01 14.99, 2.29 0.06, 0.02 8.25, 0~ 21.2~ 14.3~ 321.~ 7.52~ 51.5~ 10, ~ 5.03~ 6.3,~ 61.5~
4 Winter 4     0.04, 0    13.42, 0.13 0.1, 0.01  19.95, 1.03 0.03, 0.02 8.85, 0~ 20.3~ 15.4~ 322,~ 7.53~ 52.5~ 14, 0 2.54~ 6.25~ 66.5~
5 Winter 5     0.06, 0.01 15.14, 0.67 0.1, 0     17.03, 0.4  0.04, 0.03 9.25, 0~ 21.8~ 14.6~ 309,~ 7.38~ 69.5~ 13.5~ 10.2~ 6.2,~ 83, ~
6 Winter 6     0.05, 0.01 21.43, 0.17 0.09, 0.01 8.58, 1.72  0.01, 0.02 9, 0.42  24.9~ 11.9~ 300.~ 7.57~ 63.5~ 23.5~ 4.6,~ 5.4,~ 87, ~
```